# How to extract array of arrays values and push in same array in ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I have this array of array

```
a1 = [['one', 'two', ['three', 'four']], ['five', 'six', ['seven', 'eight']]];
```

how to get this 'three' and 'four', 'seven' and 'eight' out of child array and push it in parent array as string like below

```
a2 = [['one', 'two', 'three, four'], ['five', 'six', 'seven, eight']];
```

like this. can I solve it with ES6?

Note: with space between 'three' 'four' and 'seven' 'eight' as shown in a2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to `join` the inner arrays, yeah?

```js
let a1 = [['one', 'two', ['three', 'four']], ['five', 'six', ['seven', 'eight']]];
let merged = a1.map((values) => {
  return values.map((value) => {
    return Array.isArray(value) ? value.join(', ') : value;
  });
});
console.log(merged)
```

Comment: Not just join, values should come out of child array and show in parent array. a2 = [['one', 'two', 'three, four'], ['five', 'six', 'seven, eight']];

Comment: Try running this code, it produces the same output as in your question.

Answer (score 2):

A double `map` will do the logic.

I used `Array.isArray` method to check whether the node is array or not.

```js
a1 = [['one', 'two', ['three', 'four']], ['five', 'six', ['seven', ['eight']]]];
a2 = a1.map(node => node.map(item => Array.isArray(item) ? item.join(',') : item));
console.log(a2);
```

Comment: Hi, I am sorry made some edit to question, please check now.

Comment: @R.H I have updated the answer, please have a check.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Please remove the extra bracket in a1 for 'eight' in your answer.

Comment: But what if string is changed to any other datatype?

Comment: @R.H I have modified logic a little bit. The initial logic was treating all non string elements as array. That wont work fine with other datatypes. So I made ude of `Array.isArray` method to check whether the node is array or not. Please see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need:

```js
var a1 = [
  ['one', 'two', ['three', 'four']],
  ['five', 'six', ['seven', ['eight']]]
];

a1.map(val => {
  return val.map((elem, index) => {
    val[index] = checkElemType(elem)
    return elem
  })

})


console.log(a1)

function checkElemType(elem) {
  if (Array.isArray(elem)) {
    elem.map((obj, index) => {
      elem[index] = checkElemType(obj)
      return obj
    })
    return elem.join(",")
  }


  return elem;
}
```

Comment: Please check the input array. 'seven' 'eight' 'nine' is not as in question.

Comment: I have just added it so that it shows that it can work further too, anyways i have updated my answer